# Is it a good idea to alter MySQL system priority from default?

Tags: linux, mysql, rhel5

I'm running MySQL 5.0.x on RHEL 5.3.
I read in the MySQL Manual ([here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/linux-post-install.html)) that 'it is essential to run the mysqld process with the highest possible priority on the 2.4 kernel to achieve maximum performance' and they recommend using renice -20.

There is no mention of the 2.6 kernel.
On my system MySQL is running with a priority of 0.

I do suffer from load problems where the IOwait gets high when disk activity like copying a big file takes place during normal daytime database traffic.

Is changing the priority a good idea or are there any potential problems with doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scheduler priority will not solve your problem, it's only used to pick which process gets to use the CPU first when there are multiple waiting.

IOwait is caused by processes stuck waiting for IO to complete, in your case, the disks. It has nothing to do with the process priority, so changing it won't have any effect. The solution is to either rate limit the big file transfers, move them to another time when the machine is idle or upgrade the disks so they can handle the load better. Use iostat -xm 5 to monitor the disk utilization %, if it goes over 80%, it's bad news.

Comment: good point on the `iostat` call

Comment: Might be worth setting mysql's disk priority to 1 with ionice.

Comment: @Cian - I didn't knew you could do that. Yeah, that would make sure mysql runs smoothly no matter what happens on the background. The "load" number will still be high, but it doesn't matter that lots of processes are waiting, as long as db requests gets served first.

Just don't put mysql in the realtime class or you'll have trouble sshing into the machine. Alternatively, put the bulk processes in the idle class.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, the default runtime priority (0) is fine if you're on a mixed-use machine - ie, running a db and apache and mail, etc.

If it's *just* a db machine, I'd pump the priority up as high as it could go without sacrificing manageability (vis-a-vis ssh remote console).

Comment: If there's nothing else on the machine why use priority at all?

Comment: @Gleb - to ensure that it does get all the system priority you want it to have :) ..I do this on dedicated servers, not because it's necessarily "required", but it seems like a really Good Idea(tm) :)